# How to close the kafka consumer in python at x min?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, consumer

I am writing a kafka message to a file in python and want to close the consumer at x time.

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='xxx:xx',
                     group_id=mygroupid,
                     security_protocol='SSL',
                     ssl_check_hostname=True,
                     ssl_cafile='cccc.pem',
                     ssl_certfile='sss.pem',
                     ssl_keyfile='kk.pem',
                     auto_offset_reset='latest',
                     consumer_timeout_ms=60000)
```

using this consumer_timeout_ms=60000 my kafka is not getting close.

Answer (score 0):

So, using the `consumer_timeout_ms=60000`means that your consumer should timeout after 60 seconds of not receiving any messages. In your case, your consumer might not be closing because it's still receiving messages.

To solve this, you need to enforce a strict closing time by using something like the system clock; check the current time and close the consumer when it hits your specified time (x time).

Here's how you might implement it:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='xxx:xx',
                     group_id=mygroupid,
                     security_protocol='SSL',
                     ssl_check_hostname=True,
                     ssl_cafile='cccc.pem',
                     ssl_certfile='sss.pem',
                     ssl_keyfile='kk.pem',
                     auto_offset_reset='latest',
                     consumer_timeout_ms=60000)
while True:
    current_time = datetime.now().time()
    x_time = current_time.replace(hour=19, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    
    if current_time >= x_time:
        consumer.close()
        print(f"Consumer closed at {x_time}")
        break
```

Comment: and if i use consumer.seek_to_end() will this start from the msg we left from?

Comment: No, it won't start from the message where you left off after timeout with the code above. It will start with the recent message. You might consider storing the offset of the last message it processed in some kind of persistent storage, so you can pick up from where you left off next time you connect.